# Powershell: Using the SharePoint API, GetLocalizedString doesnt return anything

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I have a function that uses the SharePoint api so the method SPUtility.GetLocalizedString is exposed.

I have also identified the uint language numbers 1033 (english) and 1036 (french) for use as one of the parameters.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")

$en = 1033
$fr = 1036
$str = "$Resources:docliblist"
$resx = "core"
$locstr = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::GetLocalizedString($str, $resx, $en)
$locstr
$locstr = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::GetLocalizedString ("$Resources:doclibList", "core", $fr)
$locstr
```

When I run the function, $locstr is empty. Not null, just empty.

Also, when I use the function this way:

```
$str = "$Resources:core, docliblist"
$locstr = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::GetLocalizedString($str, $null, $en)
```

I get a returned value of 'docliblist'

Now, while I can just take out what I need from the resx file and put into my own config file, I am perplexed as to why this isnt working. If anyone has any advice I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

*Edit

What was the point of you changing the quotation marks?

Comment: $Resources is a powershell variable??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$Resources` isn't a powershell variable you need to escape `'$'`. Try it this way:

```
$str = "`$Resources:docliblist"
```

Comment: Surprisingly this worked. I did end up having to rework this into a feature instead of a script but this helped me out.